# pexpect ssh through multiple hosts

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

Using pexpect I want to spawn an ssh sessions and ssh connect through several server to a final server as I would do with Expect.

Version of Python: 2.7.3

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pexpect  
#import getpass  
#import time  

child = pexpect.spawn ('ssh foo@foo')  
child.expect ('P*')  
child.sendline ('blahblahblah')  
child.expect ('P*')  
child.sendline ('ssh server2.foo')  
child.expect ('P*')  
child.sendline ('blahblahblah')  
child.interact()
```

I get to my first hop no problem, login at server foo but I do not know the pexpect syntax to expect "send -- ssh $user@$host \r" for the subsequent hops.

Answer (score 0):

You can go on with sendline like you've already done

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh %s@%s' % (username, relayhost0), timeout = 5)
child.expect('P*')
child.sendline('ssh %s@%s' % (username, relayhost1))
child.expect('P*')
child.sendline('ssh %s@%s' % (username, relayhost2))
child.expect('P*')

child.interact()
```